# Cannot login to alfresco explorer or alfresco share

Tags: tomcat, alfresco, alfresco-share

Cant login to my alfresco community edition 4.2

I tried `http://127.0.0.1:8080/share/` I got `Your authentication details have not been recognized or Alfresco may not be available at this time.`

I tried `http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/` I got

```
type Status report

message /alfresco/

description The requested resource is not available.
```

I tried `http://127.0.0.1:8080` I got my tomcat homepage

What is the problem?
Do I need to install mysql and java before installing alfresco?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange, I installed without 
Sharepoint 
Google docs Integration 
Libre Office

Now its working. But how to install these components.

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco Share (/share) requires the Alfresco web application (/alfresco) to be up and running in order for you to log in successfully.

If you go to /alfresco and get an error message, it means that either your web server is not configured to allow you to connect, or, more likely, your Alfresco web application failed to start for some reason.

You should check your log (e.g., $TOMCAT_HOME/logs/catalina.out) for error messages to understand what went wrong.

> Do I need to install mysql and java before installing alfresco?

Alfresco requires Java 1.7 as well as a relational database like MySQL to run. If you installed Alfresco using the binary installer and took the default options, the installer will install PostgreSQL for you (as well as other dependencies such as ImageMagick and LibreOffice).

If you installed Alfresco some other way you'll have to install the dependencies yourself.

Comment: I installed via binary installer.I selected "Easy" while installing. I am getting alfresco share page, but I cant login.